# Unable to access Html tags present within xsl in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an html page which uses XML and XSL. And there are html tags like `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>`. I want to access these tags from javaScript and set value for its attributes from javaScript. I tried using GetElementById, GetElementByName,GetElementByTagName to access the  and  in the code posted below but was unable to do so.

Excerpts of the code:

```
<xml id="xmlSchedule" LANGUAGE=javascript onreadystatechange="return xmlSchedule_onreadystatechange()"></xml>
<xml id="xslSchedule">
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
  <xsl:template>                                                
      <table id="tblSchedule" index='0' class="GridText" style="TABLE-LAYOUT:fixed;FONT-SIZE:9pt;FONT-FAMILY:verdana;width=100%">
        <xsl:for-each select="VOE-OBJECT/ITEM">
          <tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'"> <xsl:attribute name="TWRow"></xsl:attribute>
            <td data="25" width="20" height='17' align='left'>
                <img><xsl:attribute name="SRC"><xsl:eval>getChargeIcon(this)</xsl:eval></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:eval>getChargeTitle(this)</xsl:eval></xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </td>
            <td  data="24" id='tdNote' width="20" height="17" align='middle'>
                <img><xsl:attribute name="SRC"><xsl:eval>getNoteIcon(this)</xsl:eval></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:eval>getNoteTitle(this)</xsl:eval></xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </td>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
   function XYZ() {
   var oRow = document.GetElementByName("TWRow");
    var oLength = oRow.childNodes.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < olength; i++) {
       oRow.childNodes.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("data")= i;
   }
```

And when I used document.GetElementByName("TWRow") and check in quick watch it returned a object but count was 0.

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything relevant. I am very new to XML and XSL please guide.

Comment: Anup, there is not GetElementById function, it's getElementById, did you try that?

Comment: Also note that your XSL code in the namespace http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl is a proprietary, nowadays unsupported predecessor to the W3C standard XSLT.

Comment: AFAIK <xml id=foo> is illegal, use <xml id="foo">.
Further, TWRow seems to be an attribute of <tr>, not an element.
alert( document.getElementById( "trSchedule" ) ) should show the type of object.
Also, official HTML attributes must be lowercase (SRC->src).
ALso, <xsl:template> is missing the match attribute - unless you embed it somewhere. And, I assume that the code excerpts are from different documents, because a document can only have one root node?
Btw, try running this in Chrome, it has very strict error checking.

Comment: Fernando, Ya its a typo I have made here. Its getElementById in my actual code.

Comment: Kenney, Ya there are some typos I have made here as you have pointed out. I will make those changes in the above code. What root node are you talking about? Can you plz explain? And ya Html code is in different document and JS code is in different file(corresponding .JS file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I believe you should be using "GetElementsByName" here, not "GetElementByName" (because it is valid for multiple elements the same name)

```
var oRow = document.GetElementByName("TWRow");
```

But the reason it is not finding anything is because you have no elements in your HTML with the name "TWRow". And the reason you don't is because of this XSLT

```
 <tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'">
     <xsl:attribute name="TWRow"></xsl:attribute>
```

This is actually creating an attribute called **TWRow** on your **tr** element

```
<tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'" TWRow="">
```

But for GetElementsByName to work, it needs to look like this

```
<tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'" name="TWRow">
```

To fix this, change the XSLT to as follows:

```
 <tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'">
     <xsl:attribute name="name">TWRow</xsl:attribute>
```

Or better still, just write out the attribute directly un your XSLT

```
<tr id="trSchedule" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'" name="TWRow">
```